# How to Invoke Driver Class from Oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

Is it possible to invoke driver class from oozie workflow. The example I saw is specifying the mapper and reducer.
I want to invoke the driver class as some parameters are being set from my driver class which needs to be passed.

It will be helpfull if any document link or guidance is provided.

Thanks
Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

For running any MapReduce jobs using oozie it is recommended to use `<map-reduce>` action. There are distinct advantages to being tightly integrated as a  action in Oozie instead of being just another Java program.

1. Because Oozie knows that the `<map-reduce>` action runs a Hadoop job, it provides easy access to Hadoop counters for this job. It’s a lot harder to save and access the counters of a Hadoop job if it is invoked as a `<java>` action.
2. The launcher map task that launches the `<map-reduce>` action completes immediately and Oozie directly manages the MapReduce job. This frees up a Hadoop slot for a MapReduce task that would have otherwise been occupied by the launcher task in the case of a `<java>` action.

So if you want to launch the MapReduce job using the Driver class, you can use the `<java>` action and launch it.

[OOzie Java Action Configuration](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.7_Java_Action).

Comment: Hi @YoungHobbit, thanks for answering that. It was informative. But I have a question. Suppose I am starting multiple jobs in Hadoop, where in  only one jobs, (say Job-A ) is using <java> action(i.e. uses my Driver Class), In this case once Job-A's mapper phase is done, will the other MR jobs which were started by Oozie in the cluster(not via <java> action),  start Occupying the empty Maps slots that were freed by Job-A. Will Oozie still impact my other Job runs some how ? I am new to Oozie, will be great if you can guide me on my query.! thanks..

Comment: Only one extra `container` will be used, if you launch the job via `<java>` action. The map reduce job will work like a regular MR jobs, once a mapper task is completed, it will free the container and will be available with the `ResourceManager`.